# Why don't js compressors do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always wondered why js compressors don't do this. Let's say I have a minified script like this:

```
(function($){var a=$("a");1<a.length&&10>a.length?alert(a.length):alert($("p").length)})(jQuery);
```

Why doesn't it compile to something like this:

```
(function($,L){var a=$("a");1<a[L]&&10>a[L]?alert(a[L]):alert($("p")[L])})(jQuery,'length');
```

Meaning changing every occurrence of a `.property` with a `[minified key]` and pass a string and arg receiver to the [`iife`](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (basically what I did above with the `.length`)

Imagine how much more this would minify jQuery with 159 `.length`, 62 `.each`, 15 `.appendChild` etc. Just the `.length`s alone would save over 600 bytes!

Also using the example above why does it waste space on a var keyword when you can reserve a space in that functions scope by declaring another parameter:

```
(function($,L,a){a=$("a");1<a[L]&&10>a[L]?alert(a[L]):alert($("p")[L])})(jQuery,'length');
```

Also while I have you here, why not put the entire jQuery into an eval and save on another 572 `function` keywords (4.5k)?

Comment: I used to hand write JS like that, still do sometimes. Also do some cheats with String.prototype.IO=String.prototype.indexOf or Us='undefined';Ss='string';Ow=window; and String.prototype.has(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine that it doesn't want to assume that you want the expense of a variable lookup in addition to the property lookup.

If you use Closure Compiler, it will actually undo those types of references if you do it manually.

Ultimately, if you gzip, I don't think those obfuscations add up to much. I wouldn't be surprised if in some cases it actually makes your gzipped version larger.

Answer (score 5):

Because it would change the structure of the code.  Instead of having a method that operates on the `length` property of objects, your proposal now provides a function that allows for any passed-in property name to be accessed - which may be against the intent of the original code.

There may also be performance implications for doing this - or at least, this could cause for certain optimizations in the JavaScript runtimes to not be usable.

Also keep in mind that most JavaScript source files should go through GZip compression (negotiated and done transparently at the HTTP level by most web servers/browsers) - which will easily compress out any duplicate instances of any names, including "var" and reused property names.

Comment: I don't think misuse of the function would really be a reason. It's an IIFE, so it's only invoked once with whatever arguments are given. It should be able to add parameters and arguments to the end without ramification. It would just need to be careful that there are an equal number of each.

Comment: ...unless perhaps the `arguments` object is referenced.

Comment: it would also leave extra variables floating around for closures

Comment: @jermel: They wouldn't be just floating around. They would be an active part of the code. The idea is that any nested code that uses `"length"` (for example) would need to reference the variable in order to access the property.

Answer (score 3):

Because minifiers should not change code functionality, only remove unnecessary characters.